# Echo a line of code to a file end up incomplete

Tags: bash, echo

While executing a script in bash

```
echo "export PS1='\[\e[1;32m\][\u@\h \W]\$\[\e[0m\] '" >> /home/testusername/.bash_profile
```

While I am reading the file is missing one character which is a `"\"` right after `"W]"`

Result of reading:

```
export PS1='\[\e[1;32m\][\u@\h \W]$\[\e[0m\] '
```

Manually pasted the same line of code in .bash_profile

```
export PS1='\[\e[1;32m\][\u@\h \W]\$\[\e[0m\] '
```

There is a difference of one character, what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is `'` and `"`.
if you change the sequence of them your problem will solve.

```
echo 'export PS1="\[\e[1;32m\][\u@\h \W]\$\[\e[0m\] "'
```

I refer you to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6697781/3214950) for more explanation.